# How do I set the large-arc or sweep flag in d3.svg.arc()

Tags: svg, d3.js

I'm drawing pieces of a circle with arcs using d3.
This works fine for drawing parts that start at 10 degrees to 20 degrees or even 300-350 degrees, however:

sometimes I need to draw the arc from 350 degrees to 5 degrees, so a 15 degree arc instead of the arc that runs from  5 all the way to 350. Is there a way to specify the large-arc flag,or the sweep flag when using d3.svg.arc()? (note, swapping the start and end does not make a difference with d3.svg.arc()

Answer (score 2):

I'm new to d3 so maybe there is something more straightforward.

You could define your angle as 0 -> sweep, and then rotate it counter clockwise. So, for your 350 to 5:

```
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(50)
    .outerRadius(70)
    .startAngle(0)
    .endAngle(15 * (Math.PI/180));

svg.append("path")
    .attr("d", arc)
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-10)");
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jobigoud/ecdWq/) with this.

Answer (score 0):

While d3 is low-level, with `d3.svg.arc`, you don't have to be *that* low level; just think of the range of angles you want to draw, and express that as a start and end number you can cross without discontinuities (0° -> 360° being a typical discontinuity). You can use both positive and negative angles, so using -10° for 350° makes a continues range [5…-10] ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ecmanaut/hswcx/)):

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  , r2d = Math.PI / 180
  , arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(50)
    .outerRadius(70)
    .startAngle(5 * r2d)
    .endAngle(-10 * r2d);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("d", arc)
    .attr("transform", "translate(200,200)");
```